# Set Default NFS v4 when connecting from Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, nfs

I have installed an NFS File Server on Ubuntu 11.10, and that is working well.

I am only able to connect to the NFS server from my Mac with this command:

```
 mount -t nfs -o vers=4 10.0.10.26:/srv /Users/admin/Desktop/mount
```

But I cannot connect via Finder (nfs://10.0.10.26:/srv) or through any third party programs that don't allow for the version parameter. The Syslog error is

> mount_nfs: can't mount /srv from 10.0.10.26 onto
>   /Users/admin/Desktop/mount: Program version wrong

Is there any way to set this to V4 by default? Either server side or on my Mac? I need to be able to connect without the extra parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Hmmm, seems we need to have this question re-answered every major release of OS X.

So I can only say this works on 10.10.x :)

From OS X's man page for mount_nfs

*"nfs.conf(5) can be used to configure some NFS client options. In particular, nfs.client.mount.options can be used to specify default mount options"*

To get the Finder to default to using NFS v4 add the following to /etc/nfs.conf using the terminal command "sudo vi /etc/nfs.conf"

```
 nfs.client.mount.options = vers=4
```

Again, to check after mounting use "nfsstat -m" and check the "NFS parameters".

Comment: Still works for 10.13 High Sierra, too.

Answer (score 11):

The syntax for using NFS v4 (and passing options in general) is :

```
nfs://vers=4,10.0.10.26/srv
```

You can check the mount afterwards from the Terminal using :

```
nfsstat -m
```

Comment: I found (OSX 10.9.5) that this was no good. The comma ends up in the mount command. Investigating the command it ran (from the ps list) I saw that this resulted in a command:

    `mount_nfs -odeadtimeout=45 nfsvers=2,example.com:/var/www /Volumes/www`

- which was a failure.
Experiments with other variations of spacing before the hostname seemed to help a little. Entering an nfs URL 

    `nfs:// -onfsvers=2 example.com:/var/www`

- Including those spaces looked like it should have worked, but for some reason still did not.

Comment: Can confirm that this work even on Ventura 13, and seems less hacky than applying changes to environment files.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, I just wanted to note for current users that under Big Sur I am able to use

`nfs://vers=4,myhost.mydomain.com/nfs/share`

Comment: Definitely doesn't work for me. Any special setup that you did beforehand?

Comment: Same here.  I get `mount_nfs: warning: option "nfssvers" not known`

Comment: I was not clear, sorry about that!  That syntax works in the "Connect to Server" dialog of the Finder, not as parameters to `mount` at the command line.