# Use Finder to connect to NFS server with parameters

Tags: finder, nfs

How does one specify NFS parameters when using the Finder to connect to a NFS server?

I know I can mount from the command-line... things like

```
$ mount -t nfs -o vers=4,sec=krb5p someserver:/path /mnt
```

or

```
$ mount -t nfs -o vers=4,ro,resvport someserver:/path /mnt
```

I know I can set defaults in `/etc/nfs/conf`, like this

```
nfs.client.mount.options = vers=4,sec=krb5p
```

I know the options in `/etc/nfs.conf` are applied to connections made using the Finder's *"Connect to server"* tool.

I've [read](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50647/set-default-nfs-v4-when-connecting-from-mac-os-x-lion) that options can be specified to the Finder like this

```
nfs://vers=4,someserver:/path
```

But that does not appear to work.

**Is it possible to use Finder to connect to a NFS server with parameters ?**

I'm seeking an up to date and relevant answer to this question as the [only reference I can find](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50647/set-default-nfs-v4-when-connecting-from-mac-os-x-lion) is quite old.